# What is the norm of the gradient vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Would this be the total change in the function at a given point? It seems like it would solve to a single number, and since the gradient vector gives the changes in the i,j, and k axes, then the norm would be the total change of all the axes added together. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366227/understanding-directional-derivative-and-the-gradient, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378226/why-does-nabla-fx-y-z-point-in-the-direction-of-greatest-increase-of-the, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent and many other similar questions.

Comment: What is the definition of total change?

Comment: Except of course the usual vector norm is not the absolute value on each axis "added together".